# SyntaxError: invalid syntax using path to file in 'with open'

Tags: python, io, syntax-error

I'd like to write something to 'impf_rel.txt' which is located at 'C:\Abaqus_JOBS\Reliability\Job'. I wrote:

```
with open('C:\\Abaqus_JOBS\\Reliability\\Job\\impf_rel.txt', 'w')
    text_file.write("%s" % '#imp_local\n')
    text_file.write("%s" % '#imp_global')
```

And I get:

```
with open('C:\\Abaqus_JOBS\\Reliability\\Job\\impf_rel.txt', 'w')
                                            ^
                                            SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Both the directory and the file name are correct and they exist. Can you help me with this error? Thanks

EDIT:
If I ask alternatively:

```
with open('C:\\Abaqus_JOBS\\Reliability\\impfrel.txt', 'w')
    text_file.write("%s" % '#imp_local\n')
    text_file.write("%s" % '#imp_global')
```

I still get an error:

```
with open('C:\\Abaqus_JOBS\\Reliability\\impfrel.txt', 'w')
                                            ^
                                            SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a `:` at the end

```
with open('C:\\Abaqus_JOBS\\Reliability\\Job\\impf_rel.txt', 'w') as file_handler:
#                                                                                ^
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to place `as text_file:` at the end of the with-statement:

```
with open('C:\\Abaqus_JOBS\\Reliability\\Job\\impf_rel.txt', 'w') as text_file:
    text_file.write("%s" % '#imp_local\n')
    text_file.write("%s" % '#imp_global')
```

Here is a reference on [Python's with-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

Comment: Thank you for your time and support! I couldn't see the missing ':'.